# Modify external Widget to be dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, widget

I am using an external Widget which looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/jquery-1.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
var lang="en";
var xname="www.example.com";
var g=document.createElement("script");
g.type="text/javascript";
g.async = "true";
g.src = "www.example.com/file1.js";
var instruments="A,B";
var h = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
h.parentNode.insertBefore(g, h);
</script>
<div id="div1" class="example.com-class1"></div>
<div id="div2" class="example.com-class2"></div>
```

I want to send "instruments" as variable selected from a combobox so I redesigned the code like this:

```
<select id="cmb1">
<option value="A,B">AB</option>
<option value="C,D">CD</option>
<option value="E,F">EF</option>
</select>

<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function() { BindEvent();}
function BindEvent()
{
    var elemToBind = document.getElementById ( "cmb1" );
    elemToBind.onchange = function () { doit ( elemToBind.value );
 }
}
function doit(elem)
{
var lang="en";
var xname="www.example.com";
var g=document.createElement("script");
g.type="text/javascript";
g.async = "true";
g.src = "ww.example.com/file1.js";
var instruments=elem;
var h = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
h.parentNode.insertBefore(g, h);
}
</script>
<div id="div1" class="example.com-class1"></div>
<div id="div2" class="example.com-class2"></div>
```

But that did not work. I also tried to delete the existing result and reproduce it, but without success. When put into the "doit" function, the code doesn't work.
Every help is welcome

Comment: I wouldn't add a `<script>` each time a user changes their selection because if they go back and forth, you're just adding more & more copies of the same script. Why do you need to load an external script? Couldn't you set a variable to change the instruments?

Comment: The final version should remove the old script and create a new one with the new variable, but first I have to make it run. But it doesn't when defining it as function ("doit").